# XHTTP request from REST API

Tags: javascript, asp.net, api

I have this API

```
[HttpGet("data")]
public dynamic GetData(){
    return context.DataTable.ToList();
}
```

I tried calling it on my Javascript using this snippet;

```
function getData(){
    var xhttp = XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "api/myclass/data", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
    xhttp.send();
    var resp = xhttp.responseText;
}
```

However, it only returns empty `XMLHttpRequest`.

I think what's wrong there is the URL. How I may able to call the API to my Javascript?

Comment: Are you able to see data on that URL?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Yes, Sir.

Comment: @Salman status is 0

Comment: We don't have such a response. please check this.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @Salman I can't seem to find any relative status here on my end aside from the status entity of `XMLHttpRequest` that says 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since u have not cheked the response of ur answer, i susspect there is something wrong in ur backend. But, here is a sample of functional solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<div id="demo">
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     console.log("Status is: "+this.status);
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "xmlhttp_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You van find more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp). But in the line

```
xhttp.open("GET", "api/myclass/data", true);
```

The second parameter is the address of a file in ur server. r u sure u have wrotten the correct format?  what is the extension of ur `data` file.

I guess, both backend and front end should be reconsidered. To do it:

1. Try to send a reuqest using postman to backend
2. in frontend check the status of response using my answer
3. To make sure make it `async = false` with

   xhttp.open("GET", "api/myclass/data", false);

Therefore, there wouldn't be a delay as @Alex Kudryashev pointed

---

Solution:

You need to first find the result of line

```
console.log("Status is: "+this.status);
```

in ur browser's console.

If u get the `responseText` as empty it may come because u have sent an empty string from backend,(we are not sure because u have not tested ur backend with postman) **but it is crucial to know the status of response.**

Comment: The API can now be called. However, the data wasn't feed to the variable. Got any idea, Sir?

Comment: The `responseText` returns empty string and not the requested data.

Comment: It worked now. I changed `async = false` as you advice. Thank you so much! Life saver.

Answer (score 1):

The request may take time to receive the response so you have to wait. Something like this.

```
function getData(){
    var xhttp = XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "api/myclass/data", true); //the request is asynchronous
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if(this.readyState == 4 && this.state == 200){ //**this** is xhttp
          //data are received and ready to use
          var resp = this.responseText;
          //do whatever you want with resp but never try to **return** it from the function
       }
    }
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
    xhttp.send();
    //var resp = xhttp.responseText; //too early ;(
}
```

Comment: The api can now be pulled, however, the data wasn't feed to the variable.

Comment: @pruuylan see my answer, and do a `console.log("Status is: "+this.status);`. what is the result?

Comment: add `console.log(this);` after `if` line to see the structure of the response.